# How to recursively print linked list in reverse by passing linked list reference as parameter [homework]

Tags: java

For this assignment I need to recursively print a linked list in reverse with a linked list as the parameter, not a node.

I also have to use this SinglyLinkedList class that my professor provided:

```
 public class SinglyLinkedList<E> {
  private int length; // # elements in the linked list
  private SLNode<E> head; // access point to the linked list
  private SLNode<E> tail;

  public SinglyLinkedList() {
    this.length = 0;
    this.tail = new SLNode<E> (); // the tail dummy node
    this.head = new SLNode<E> ( null, this.tail ); // the head dummy node
  }

  public int getLength() {
    return this.length;
  }

  public void add( E e ) {
    SLNode<E> newnode = new SLNode<E> ( e, null );
    newnode.setSuccessor( this.head.getSuccessor() );
    this.head.setSuccessor( newnode );
    this.length++;
  }

  public void add( E e, int p ) {
    // verify that index p is valid
    if ( ( p < 0 ) || ( p > this.length ) ) {
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException( "index " + p
                                           + " is out of range: 0 to " +
                                           this.length );
    }
    SLNode<E> newnode = new SLNode<E> ( e, null );
    SLNode<E> cursor = this.head;
    for ( int i = 0; i < p; i++ ) {
      cursor = cursor.getSuccessor();
    }
    addAfter( cursor, newnode );
    this.length++;
  }

  public E remove( int p ) {
    if ( ( p < 0 ) || ( p >= this.length ) ) {
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException( "index " + p
                                           + " is out of range: 0 to " +
                                           ( this.length - 1 ) );
    }
    SLNode<E> cursor = head; // good for p == 0
    if ( p > 0 ) {
      cursor = find( p - 1 ); // get target's predecessor
    }

    SLNode<E> target = cursor.getSuccessor(); // get the node to remove

    // link target to cursor's successor
    cursor.setSuccessor( target.getSuccessor() );
    target.setSuccessor( null );
    cursor.setElement( null );
    this.length--;
    return target.getElement();
  }

  public E getElementAt( int p ) {
    SLNode<E> node = this.find( p );
    return node.getElement();
  }

  private void addAfter( SLNode<E> p, SLNode<E> newnode ) {
    newnode.setSuccessor( p.getSuccessor() );
    p.setSuccessor( newnode );
  }

  private SLNode<E> find( E target ) {
    SLNode<E> cursor = head.getSuccessor();

    while ( cursor != tail ) {
      if ( cursor.getElement().equals( target ) ) {
        return cursor; // success
      }
      else {
        cursor = cursor.getSuccessor();
      }
    }
    return null; // failure
  }

  private SLNode<E> find( int p ) {
    if ( ( p < 0 ) || ( p >= this.length ) ) {
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    SLNode<E> cursor = head.getSuccessor();
    int i = 0;

    while ( i != p ) {
      cursor = cursor.getSuccessor();
      i++;
    }

    return cursor;
  }

}
```

I can't figure out how to write that method with passing in a reference to a singly-linked list instead of a node. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Think about it -- if you walk the list and print as you go you will print the list in "forward" order.  If you walk the list to the end and then retrace your steps backwards, printing on each backward step, you will print the list in "reverse" order.  You can "walk" the list with a recursive call, and then a return is a "step backwards".

Comment: Though I don't offhand see a way to do this without "walking the nodes", vs using only the above public methods.  Seems like the only way to do that would be to walk the list (either by using elementAt or by removing the head node as you walked) and build up a new list as you walked, and then print that new list.

Comment: Can the list be modified (destroyed) during printing? Or should it be retained?

Comment: I believe I can modify the list during printing.

Comment: @JustinBushy no analyze what Hot Licks just said, think about how recursion acts like a stack (first called last out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base case is the list being empty, nothing left to print. So that's what we check for first. If base case is met, we return without printing anything. Otherwise the list has elements remaining, so we take the last element from the list (since we are printing in reverse) and pop it off the list. The remove method returns the removed element so that should do the trick. Now we recurse with our modified list (minus the last element). Eventually the list will be empty and all elements will have been printed in reverse.

```
public static <E> void printReverse(final SinglyLinkedList<E> list) {
    if(list.getLength() > 0) {
        System.out.println(list.remove(list.getLength()-1));
        printReverse(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't looked into your code deeply, but simply printing should be quite trivial:

in psuedo code:

```
printLinkedListInReverse(node) {
   if (node has no next) {
       print out node itself
   } else {
       printLinkedListInReverse(node's next)
       print out node itself
   }
}
```

In brief, to print in reverse, you want to print out the remaining list excluding itself first, and the print the node itself

---

If you cannot get hold of the internal node, and the linked list is subjected to modification, then the way is still similar:

```
printLinkedListInReverse(list) {
   if (list is empty) {
       //do nothing
   } else {
       firstElement = list.remove(0)
       printLinkedListInReverse(list)  // print the remaining list first
       print firstElement
   }
}
```

Comment: I understand how to print the list in reverse passing in a node reference as the parameter. But, I have to pass in a SinglyLinkedList reference.

Comment: I thought you are going to add this as method of that `SinglyLinkedList`.  If your code has no way to access the internal node, then please see my update

Comment: if you want the list looks unaltered, you can even first create of copy of list and use the above method, or you can put `firstElement` back to the first position of list after you printed it